# como puedo crear un trigger con condicionales?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedure

hola a todos tengo pensando hacer un trigger que me inserte en unta tabla log una accion que se haya realizado en la tabla relacionada o tabla principal dependiendo de la accion miren en la tabla log tengo 2 campos fecha y la accion que se realize si se hace un insert pues que en en el campo accion me inserte la accion de insertar o si fue un delete pues que inserte que fue un delete claro con la fecha en la que se hizo , como puedo hacerlo? se puede con condicionales?

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Recuerda que puedes editar tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario y añadir la info relevante (en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta). La opción editar está justo bajo la pregunta y las etiquetas!
Inténtalo y trae los errores que encuentres al intentarlo

Comment: Si lees la documentación, puedes ver que puedes especificar bajo cual acción se dispara el trigger.